# File upload "Error Empty file upload result"

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I use JQuery file upload at https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ demo example
My file upload is okay but is shows
"Error Empty file upload result"
It seems I missed the call back function.  Any suggestion to fix this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.  JSON response format needs to match the new standard.
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http://example.org/files/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://example.org/files/thumbnail/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http://example.org/files/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}